# can't implement MPMoviePlayerController without an @property

Tags: ios, objective-c, mpmovieplayercontroller

i want to two MPMoviePlayerControllers. so i started by adding this in an action method after a button is tapped:

```
MPMoviePlayerController *movieController= [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL: yURL];
[movieController prepareToPlay];
[movieController.view setFrame: self.view.bounds];  
[self.view addSubview: movieController.view];
[movieController play];
```

this doesn't work! i was following this approach so that i can add another player on the same view. but when i tried adding this to .h

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) MPMoviePlayerControllers *moviePlayer;
```

and this to .m

```
self.movieController= [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL: yURL
[self.movieController.view setFrame: self.view.bounds]; 
[self.view addSubview: self.movieController.view];
[self.movieController play];
```

it works perfectly! can anybody explain that to me? and how can i add multiple video players in a view like in the case of populating a table where each cell has a player in it?

Answer (score 1):

In the first example, you're declaring your movieController inside of the method. This means that the scope of the variable is the method, and when the method ends, the variable is deallocated. The subview that you added now doesn't point to anything, so the movie player doesn't show up.

When you declare the variable to be a property, it exists for the lifetime of your object. You can access and set its value as long as your object still exists. When you assign the value to the property, its value is being stored after the return of the method, so the view appears.

Comment: oh okay.. thanks for the explanation. but any idea of how to add multiple Movie players in a view? i don't want to show them full screen (that's why i'm not using MPMoviePlayerViewController). in multiple i mean there is no static number since i'm populating over a server and it differs in number of movie posts.

Comment: Are you sure that's a good idea? You probably won't have very much space to display all the content if you do that. Why not use a table view of movies and then have a MPMoviePlayerController come up when you tap the row?

Comment: i'll be adding them to a scroll view. so when the user scroll he will tap the video he wants to watch and he will be able to watch it. (similar to Vine's UI but not with automatic play as i don't want the user to be using so much MegaBytes when he's on 3G/4G) anyway, you made me think again about it. your way is feasible.